# Compare changed fields in @PreAuthorize function

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm writing a spring application which uses spring-data-rest to expose a restish API for CRUD operations on my entities.

I'm using role based permissions and most of my entity repositories have either a `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN')` or `@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('USER')` annotation to restrict access.

For updatng the `Person` entity (containing username, password and roles), I would like to have a slightly more complicated logic:

- users with the ADMIN role may do everything
- a user should be able edit their own `Person` entity (except the `role` property)
- only `ADMIN`s can edit the `role` property

I've tried to implement those conditions in a custom `isUpdateAllowed` method

```
    @PreAuthorize("@personAuthorizationChecker.isUpdateAllowed(#entity,principal)")
    @Override
    <S extends Person> S save(S entity);
```

```
    public boolean isUpdateAllowed(Person updatedEntity, PersonSecurityDetails principal) {
        if (principal.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + Role.ADMIN))) {
            return true;
        }
        
        Person existingState = personRepository.getById(updatedEntity.getId());

        if (updatedEntity.getRoles() != existingState.getRoles()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (loggedInPersonProvider.getLoggedInUser().getId() == principal.getId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that `Person existingState = personRepository.getById(updatedEntity.getId());` returns the exact same object as the `updatedEntity` argument. So I can't check the changes requested by the client.

I'm surprised by this. I was expecting that `updatedEntity` contains the changes requested by the client, while `existingState` contains the currently persisted state in the database. But when I look in the debugger, both are the exact same object.

[image]

Even though I'm sure that the requested changes are not already persisted to the DB.

How can I force receiving an updated entity from the DB?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By detaching the updatedEntity before querying for the entity, you will ensure that you receive the current state of the entity from the database.

Comment: Indeed, I do get the state from the DB when calling `entityManager.detach(updatedEntity); Person existingState = personRepository.getById(updatedEntity.getId()); entityManager.refresh(existingState);`. But then I get a `is org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class Person$HibernateProxy$9fwrEh8h!` when the JpaRepository actually tries to persist the entity after my PreAuthorize method returned true. Any idea how to resolve this? I keep thinking this should be a simple task, and I'm overcomplicating things

Comment: Workaround for me is now to run a native query directly with jdbc.